# debian 10 buster gnome wayland. How to make my terminal transparent?

Tags: debian, terminal, gnome, transparency, wayland

I just updated Debian from stretch to buster. It now uses Gnome Wayland. Before I had my terminal transparent using devilspie2. Now that doesn't work anymore. I guess it is because gnome now uses wayland. Is there a way to make my terminal background transparent again?

Comment: I realize that if I logout, on the login screen, I can select either GNOME or X11 in that way I can go back to old x11 having transparency whenever I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Install mate-terminal

```
sudo apt install mate-terminal
```